# error with AutoCompleteTextView on choosing Item

Tags: android, select, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I am working with auto Complete Text View. when I choose item from it, it is displaying first Item instead of showing selected item.
here is my code

```
Utilities.setAutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(this, districtsNameList, district);

            district.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                   //selectedDistrict = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    selectedDistrict = districtsNameList.get(position);
                    Log.d("tag","============positioj===="+position)
                    Log.d("tag", "22222222222222222222222222===" + selectedDistrict);
                    district.setText(selectedDistrict);
                }
            });
```

and it is the adapter Method

```
 public static void setAutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList,
                                                  AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView) {
        int layoutItemId = android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, layoutItemId, arrayList);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

// have you increased the size of Threshold

```
    public static void setAutoCompleteTextViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList,
                                                  AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView) {
        int layoutItemId = android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, layoutItemId, arrayList);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // here you have to change the code
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(3);

}
```

Comment: what does this mean? please explain me. I set it as **0**

Comment: I have edited my answer copy the code and test he result.

Comment: no, not working. You changed threshold only. it means displaying suggestions after entering 3 characters. I think it is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make Custom textview for show selected item text, have look

list_view_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Item name here..."
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now set adapter like this:

```
myAdapter = new YourAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_row_item, list);
            myAutoComplete.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Now implement itemClick listener like this:

```
 myAutoCompleteText.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {

                    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) arg1;
                    TextView tv = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(0);
                    myAutoComplete.setText(tv.getText().toString());                         
                }     
            });
```

Comment: can U share your answer using Array Adapter.